# Firebase not returning data or any error in flutter realtime database

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure like this in my realtime database[image: db struct]

I need to access the values of both fromTime & toTime. Here is my code below

```
final databaseRef=await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("fromTimeMaintenance").get();

try{
  databaseRef.children.forEach((element) {
    var props = element as Map;
    print(props["fromTimeMaintenance"]);
  });
}catch(e){
  debugPrint("No data found $e");
}
```

I am not getting any error or the result either.. Also database reference object contains database_url as null

Please help me with this
Thanks

Comment: Yes i am able to get the reference object of database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
final databaseRef = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().get();
final fromTime = databaseRef.child("fromTimeMaintenance").value;
final toTime = databaseRef.child("toTimeMaintenance").value;
```

The variables `fromTime` and `toTime` would contain the value. First you need to add a reference only to the parent, because the nodes are immediately above the parents. For example if you had the following schema:

```
users
   name: peter
   employee: 1
```

Then you would do:

```
final databaseRef = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("user").get();
```

Here you would reference the node `user` and then use the `children` property to iterate inside the `user` object.

Comment: There was a issue with the emulator .Worked on real device. Commenting because it may help someone in future